# How to call multiple functions in ng-keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Edit: This is the crux of what I'm asking.

Here's my html code:

```
<input id="newTagInput" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 && vm.addTag() ; vm.toggleClick()">
```

When the user presses enter (keycode = 13) , I need to perform vm.addTag() and vm.toggleClick(). How do I do this? What is wrong with the syntax? I do not really understand the angular documentation on this.

Comment: Why not just have a single wrapper function in place of vm.toggleClick(), that calls toggleClick() and whatever other functions you need to call.

Comment: From objective description I don't even see what you need `ng-keyup` for. Also you have `vm.newTag` as both a model and a function..... can't be both

Comment: ToggleClick() does something really simple, basically does this.clicked = !this.clicked. If that helps solve the particular problem. But I'm also looking for a general answer to the question, so that I can learn.

Comment: The post is rather unclear. It would help if you extend the code the bit into an [mcve]. Apart from a repro, some things in your text and question title are unclear too: you mix talking about *clicks* and *key-up* events. It's also a bit unclear why the question title subtly but importantly differs from the one-line question in the post body ("functions" vs "events"). Please review the post and edit to clarify.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Your solution works, but I was looking for a general answer to how to call multiple functions with ng-keyup, or if it was possible to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call multiple functions in an ng-keyup, you can wrap your desired functions in a comma separated array. Like so:

```
<input id="newTagInput" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode === 13 && [vm.addTag(), vm.toggleClick()]">
```